Proposed update to our FAQ Page
As one of the 7 essential questions we should be asking here on meta is:

What should be on our FAQ

I would like to bite the bullet and propose the following as the text for the first section.
Note that we can't change the section title, and the line "Please look around to see..." is also fixed.

What kind of questions can I ask here?
LEGO® Answers - Stack Exchange is for LEGO and building block enthusiasts. If you use LEGO or one of a number of compatible systems that share similar building techniques, and need answers to your questions (or would like to answer questions about these systems), this is place for you.
The best questions are those that have specific answers; LEGO Answers is not a general discussion forum. In general, if you have a question which covers:

Building techniques for a particular part of a model
The history of The LEGO Group or elements
Care and organisation of your bricks
Techniques for getting the best out of your Mindstorms Robots
Replicating advanced building techniques in CAD applications (i.e. LEGO Digital Designer or LDraw based applications)

Then you're in the right place.
This is not the right site for questions about:

Computer games - for game play tips and other questions, see Gaming - Stack Exchange
General support for LEGO related software (i.e. LDraw/LEGO Digital Designer/NXT alternatives), try either their dedicated support channels or Super User

Before you ask your question, though, consider the following:

We want the questions on our site to be valuable sources of information for the whole Internet, not just our community members, so we try to keep subjective opinions out of our questions and answers when we can. Share your personal play experiences and viewpoints, but avoid argument.
Community members can and will edit your questions and answers to be clear, grammatically correct and in doing so may also edit them to conform with the LEGO Group's Fair Play requirement.
Community members will vote up clearly asked, cogent, reasoned questions and answers and vote down off topic, incoherent, or inflammatory questions and answers.
We don't want the information on our site to become obsolete, and so we try not to ask questions whose answers may change with time. This means we don't re-ask the same question once it's been answered - nor do we encourage speculative answers for which we have no definitive answer.
If you want more information on a question that already exists on the site, you can edit the question, add more answers, add comments, or even ask a related question. If you ask a question identical to an existing one, your question will be closed as a duplicate, with a link directing everyone to the existing question.

If you think your question might be appropriate but aren't sure, you can also drop into our Chat rooms or ask on our Meta site.

I think we've done a reasonably good job so far on questions 1, 3 and 6 (for now, I hope you think we're doing a good job), we've started 5, but I didn't get much response to my last attempt at this.
You can also join us over in chat to discuss this and other aspects of our FAQs.

Tagged as f-r as technically it's a "Change to existing functionality", but I'm keen to see what people think first.

This is well organized and clearly written, I think. On the FAQ question about reputation, I was a bit confused because I did not come to this group from the "main site" but from links through other LEGO fans. The references to the "main site" don't seem to be relevant to the use of this group.

@62Bricks cheers :) Do you mean the section on the FAQ here? If so when that talks about "main site" it means the "blue" LEGO Answers site, rather than this meta site - the real LEGO Answers FAQ where this will go probably makes more sense - does that help?

Let us continue this discussion in chat

I've put this live on our Main FAQ, feel free to propose changes :)

I think we should accept questions for LDD, which as much as a product of LEGO as NXT-G is.

Yes, I clearly need to reword that section a bit: we should probably accept question on how to use things like LDD, but we didn't do well answering general support questions like "it's not working, why?" see my comments in main chat

@Ambo100 - I've added a bullet point for CAD/LDD supported questions - is that better?
